# How to check for Specific Item checked or Unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf

i made check box in wpf ,Got it from Internet.I want to see which item is checked or unchecked.Any idea how to do this
here goes the code

**Class**

```
public class CheckedListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
List<CheckedListItem> AvailablePresentationObjects = new List<CheckedListItem>();
        CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            item = new CheckedListItem();
            item.Id = i;
            item.Name = i.ToString();
            item.IsChecked = false;
            AvailablePresentationObjects.Add(item);

        }
        list.ItemsSource = AvailablePresentationObjects;
```

**XMAL**

```
<ListBox x:Name="list"  Margin="3,277,0,0" Height="234" VerticalAlignment="Top" Selec
tionMode="Extended">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <my:RibbonCheckBox Label="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"  />
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

took it from Here
[Checked ListBox](http://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/)

**Question is**

> How to implement property change so
>   that i can know which item was checked
>   and which was unchecked

[My Code solution](http://cid-9ce8d980da2ba458.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=9CE8D980DA2BA458!120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get collection of [selected items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx): `list.SelectedItems`.
Each item you can cast to `CheckedListItem` and check that item is checked.
If you want to handle property changing, you should implement interface [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)  in `CheckedListItem` class

Example of INotifyPropertyChanged:
Add this to your class and call `OnPropertyChanged` in properties:

```
    private boolean _isChecked;
    public boolean IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: i donot know how to implement interface can you give me some example in this case?

Comment: Thanks it is great help.One more thing that OnPropertyChanged should be when Listbox is clicked? there is no OnPropertyChanged in listboxproperties

Comment: when listbox item is clicked, IsChecked.set will called. In ListBox properties all properties are dynamically updateable

Comment: SelectionChanged raises when you select item in list, but not when you clicked your checkbox.

Comment: i checked when ever listbox item is checked or unchecked program enters in this class but how can i use it in code like for example when any checkbox is clicked messagebox shows the id or name?sorry if i am teasing yu

Comment: oh, that is simple. In SelectionChanged event you can get AddedItems and RemovedItems from event argument and do what you want with this. All objects in AddedItems or RemovedItems are also references to items from your List<CheckedListItem>

Comment: Well it never Enters in SelectionChanged  Event

Comment: i think it is due to ribbon checked box.i just need now to get the name or id of which checkbox was clicked

Comment: I have placed the solution here Please check
http://cid-9ce8d980da2ba458.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=9CE8D980DA2BA458!120

Comment: Just add event handler for each CheckedListBoxItem on PropertyChanged event and check that property is "IsChecked" and first argument of handler is CheckedListBoxItem. Also you can just iterate over collection of items and check what you need